# Lemma regarding Jordan Form

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form

Here is the lemma:
If $N \in L(V )$ is nilpotent, then there exist vectors
$v_1,\dots,v_n\in V$ and nonnegative integers $m_1,\dots,m_n$ such that

(a) $(N^{m_1}(v_1),\ldots,N(v_1),v1; \ldots ;N^{m_n}(v_n),\ldots N(v_n),v_n)$ is a basis of $V$ and

(b) $N^{m_1+1}(v_1)=\ldots =N^{m_n+1}(v_n)=0$

(The proof is by induction on $\dim(V)$. I need to show the base case($\dim(V=1$)). All the proofs I have seen say this is trivial.  However, I need to show it precisely, and in detail)
Help?

Comment: For the case $\dim V=1$?

Comment: You need to learn latex.  I tried to fix it for you but your (a) is confusing you have "N^m1(v1)" and "N(v1)" and "v1" what exactly do you mean?

Comment: Yes, for the case dimV=1.  Also, in response to Gregory, when I write v1, I mean v with subscript 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a proof of the base case: Assume that $\dim V = 1$. This implies that every linear operator on $V$ is multiplication by a scalar. Thus the only nilpotent operator on $V$ is the $0$ operator. With that information, we have $N = 0$ and we can take $n = 1$, $v_1$ to be any nonzero vector in $V$, and $m_1 = 0$.

Comment: Thanks! I am thrilled to have your help. I have been studying your textbook this semester!